# Regularity of boundary of a level set of a $C^{1,\alpha}$ function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{1,\alpha}$ function. Denote $S_C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid f(x)=C \}$ the level set of $f$ with value $C$.

What i want to ask is, if $S_C$ is nonempty for some $C$, then whether each connect component of $S_C$ has a $C^{1,\alpha}$ boundary? What i know is, connect component of $S_C$ may be a curve, or a set with positive Lesbague measure.

Moreover, if $S_C$ is nonempty and has positive Lesbague measure for some $C$, then whether $S_C$ has a connect component which has positive Lesbague measure and $C^{1,\alpha}$ boundary? Or whether $S_C$ has a subset with positive measure and $C^{1,\alpha}$ boundary?

Answer (score 4):

For every closed set $E \subset \mathbf{R}^2$, you can construct a *smooth* function $f: \mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$ which has the level set $\{ f = 0 \} = E$. In particular, nothing can be said about the regularity of its boundary. (What you say about level sets - namely that they must either be a curve or a set with positive Lebesgue measure - seems inaccurate in this light.)

In fact, the construction is not too difficult. If $\varphi$ is a standard bump function, then you can just take $f = \varphi(\mathrm{dist}(\cdot,E))$.